# Xdebug var_dump formatting osx

Tags: php, macos, xdebug

I have installed xdebug using brew (`brew install php55-xdebug`), I can see it loaded in when I print phpinfo(). I walked through stackoverflow and found in the answers that these properties should be set to these values as I did:

`HTML_ERRORS` are `ON`
[image: html_errors]

`xdebug.overload_var_dump` is `ON`
[image: xdebug.overload_var_dump]

`xdebug.remote_autostart` is `ON`
[image: xdebug.remote_autostart]

`xdebug.default_enable` is `ON`
[image: xdebug.default_enable]

And my question is why my `var_dump` outputs aren't formatted with colors etc.

When I use `xdebug_var_dump()` it's not colored either.

The only thing I can achieve is this ⬇︎ by adding `<pre>` tags but can't get those colors working... Thanks

[image: var_dump screen]

Comment: That config should work, as far as I know. What happens if you use `xdebug_var_dump()` instead of `var_dump()`?

Comment: When I use `xdebug_var_dump()` it's not colored either

Answer (score 1):

Set `xdebug.cli_color = 2` to your `/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini` file. See [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/display):

> If this setting is 1, Xdebug will color var_dumps and stack traces output when in CLI mode and when the output is a tty. On Windows, the ANSICON tool needs to be installed.
>
> If the setting is 2, then Xdebug will always color var_dumps and stack trace, no matter whether it's connected to a tty or whether ANSICON is installed. In this case, you might end up seeing escape codes.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
xdebug.default_enable = 1
```